# Set error message for validation of non-nullable types

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I use ASP.NET core 3.1

I have:

```
class A
{
    public int A {get;set;}
}
```

When I send json model `{"A": null}` I get `"error": "INVALID"`. But I wait "REQUIRED".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#required-validation-on-the-server

I tried do as written above, but it doesn't work.

```
options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(
            _ => "The field is required.");
```

How can I customize the message?

Comment: Did you consider using a nullable int?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen yes, it works if [Required] attribute is set. But I interest do with not-nullable.

Comment: You can get the error message you set in ModelState=>Values=>Errors(in my answer picture)And then the error message will shown in the view.

Answer (score 1):

as a trick, you could use the special field as string and cast it in receiver place!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you cannot get the error message in controller?Here is a worked demo:

TestInt:

```
public class TestInt
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public string b { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        public ActionResult CheckA() {
           
            return View();
        }
        [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public ActionResult CheckA(TestInt testInt)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var item in ModelState)
                {
                    string key = item.Key;
                    var errors = item.Value.Errors;

                    foreach (var error in errors)
                    {
                        result.Append(key + " " + error.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }

                TempData["Errors"] = result.ToString();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="a" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="a" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="a" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="b" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="b" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="b" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Test" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllers()
                .AddMvcOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(
                        _ => "REQUIRED");
                });
```

result：
[image]